# Print remote machine output

Tags: linux, output, remote-server, systemctl

I have a script

```
ssh node1 "systemctl stop a1"
ssh node2 "systemctl stop a2"
ssh node3 "systemctl stop a3"
ssh node4 "systemctl stop a*"
ssh node5 "systemctl stop a1*"
ssh node6 "systemctl stop a3*"
```

It does the job, but I would like to get the output of systemctl command logged on the machine where I run the script. Is it possible? And any pointers?

`echo $?` will print the code, any way to get the contents or any way to store it in the remote machine and verify via another command.

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the output of your commands and simply redirect the output in a text file on the remote machine.

Example:
`ssh node1 "systemctl stop a1" >> log.txt`

Where log.txt is the log text file where the output of your command will be stored and the '>>' operator puts the ouput of the file in a new line every single time a command is run.

**Be careful** not to put the '>' operator as it simply overwrites the previously written text in the log.txt.

Hope this helps!